# Why can't websockets with iteratees supply separate types for the input frames and output frames?

Tags: scala, playframework

According to the play docs [on WebSockets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-different-types-of-messages), you can use different types for input frames and output frames provided you supply a FrameFormatter for each type. This makes sense.

However, on the [WebSocket object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.WebSocket$) all the factory methods that deal with Iteratees take a single type parameter `[A]` whereas the methods implemented with Actors take two type parameters `[In, Out]`. I don't see why it wouldn't be just as useful to use separate types for input and output with iteratees as with Actors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that they can have separate types for both, but play does not provide an easy API for this use case. To get the most control over a websocket, don't use the convenience constructors, but instead use the actual constructor directly, which is declared as:

```
case class WebSocket[In, Out]
  (f: RequestHeader => Future[Either[Result, (Enumerator[In], Iteratee[Out, Unit]) => Unit]])
  (implicit val inFormatter: WebSocket.FrameFormatter[In], val outFormatter: WebSocket.FrameFormatter[Out])
```

[Source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/WebSocket.scala)